# UTBB technology

Tags: fet, finfet

I'm studying technological aspects of electronics but I don't understand what UTBB is. In particular, I do not understand the difference between UTB (Ultra Thin Body) and UTBB (Ultra Thin Body and Buried oxide). What are the consequences, advantages and disadvantages of having also a thin buried oxide?

Thanks

Comment: I advise you to include more context, for example a link to an article where you found these terms. I am familiar with IC technology but not with Finfet and never heard about UTB and UTBB before.

Comment: Hi, thanks for repling. I've heard of UTB and UTBB during a seminar so I don't have an article to link. I apoligize for this. Practically speaking an UTB-FET is a FET device whose body is very thin so that it is completely depleted, everything is done using SOI wafers. Here you can find something about UTB:
https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-138.pdf (page 7)
For what concerns UTBB, I don't really know, I've heard of it but didn't understand so much. In the following article UTBB is mentioned:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038110115003275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTBB technology has both BOX (Buried Oxide) and body thin, this introduces the possibility to tune the threshold of the FET leading to what is called multi-threshold technology. Threshold can be varied thanks to the presence of the second gate (back gate).

Answer (score 0):

I read a bit an I'll give it a go. I'm not an expert in this field so if anyone has more accurate knowledge, please share.

In [this article](http://www.soiconsortium.org/fully-depleted-soi/presentations/june-2013/Nobuhiko%20Noto%20-%20UTBB%20Wafer_SEH_June2013.pdf) from a wafer manufacturer they show that they make wafers for SOI processes with 25 nm BOX (Buried Oxide) and on top of that 12 nm SOI (Silicon on Insulator). These are used for SOI processes (obviously) which are needed for UTB transistors.

An UTB transistor is made in that thin, 12 nm slice of SOI. Compared to a traditional bulk MOS transistor (which has a bulk with the same thickness as the wafer, usually 0.1 - 0.5 mm) that is a very thin bulk. This reduces parasitic capacitances and therefore increases speed and lowers power consumption.

I think that UTB and UTBB are basically the same thing. To make an UTB transistor you need an isolated layer of silicon. This is what the BOX layer does, it provides insulation for the SOI layer. I do not see how one could make a UTB without using a BOX. So I think that UTB must also include that Oxide layer so it must essentially be the same as UTBB.

So probably just two different abbreviations for basically the same thing.

Comment: It sounds strange since the one who gave me this terms made a clear distintion between UTB and UTBB... I don't think absence of the second "B" means no bulk but rather "thin bulk". I'm wondering whether it could be something related to double gate technology. Anyway, I will go deeper thanks

Comment: Edit: I don't think absence of the second "B" means no BODY but rather "thin BODY"